# add a simple pre formatting to mojolicious lite app

Tags: html, perl, mojolicious

I am following the Mojolicious lite tutorial but struggling to generate a page with the `<pre>content</pre>` formatting.

Waht do I need to change so that the output is formatted as a block of `<pre>content</pre>` HTML?

Here is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                      
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;

get '/foo' => sub ($c) {
  my $id = $c->param("id");
  my $cmd = "perl /home/user/tool.pl -id $id 2>&1";
  my $ret = `$cmd`;
  # $c->render(text => $id);                                                                             
  $c->render(text => $ret, layout => 'default');
};

app->start;
__DATA__
@@ layouts/foo.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <pre>
    %= content
  </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The text renderer does not use layouts. You have to use an ep template with a layout file and use the ep renderer. (Which is the default if you call `render()` without args).

Also note that `stash()` is used to pass data to the template.

```
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;

get '/foo' => sub ($c) {
  my $id = $c->param("id");

  my $ret = 'test';
  # $c->render(text => $id);
  $c->stash(ret => $ret);
  $c->render();
};

app->start;
__DATA__
@@ foo.html.ep
    % layout 'def';
    %= $ret
@@ layouts/def.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <pre>
    %= content
  </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```